# Instgarm API user search

Tags: php, instagram-api

how can I use the Instagram API to search for users by name and embed it on the site?
For example search the user test1 will give me a link to his profile

Thank you

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/ - did you know the instagram API is being disabled except for business accounts? Anyway we're not really here to read the documentation on your behalf...did you research or try anything before asking others to do it for you?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use instagram private API like this: 
[Instagram Private API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

there so many example & method you can simply use, don't forget to read the [Wiki](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/wiki) for more details.